# Protein A-antibody SDS-PAGE

Tags: antibody, gel-electrophoresis

I wanted to know whether the boiling of Protein A- antibody complex for SDS-PAGE analysis will disrupt the interaction? and result in dissociation of protein A and antibody?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Samples for SDS-PAGE are mixed with a loading buffer containing SDS (final concentration of SDS is usually 2%). Generally, the SDS will disrupt protein-protein interactions, even before boiling. Reducing agent (usually DTT or b-mercaptoethanol) is added to disrupt disulfide bonds.
See diagram [here](https://www.mblintl.com/products/sds-polyacrylamide-gel-electrophoresis-mbli/).

There are, however, exceptions. Some protein complexes/multimers are resistant to SDS until boiling, and some even maintain interactions after boiling. Some examples: [Xia et al 2007](https://www.pnas.org/content/104/44/17329.long), [Kubista et al 2004](https://jcs.biologists.org/content/117/6/955.long), [Grigorian et al 2009](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1110/ps.041048805).